# RenameTo with openjdk-6-jdk

Tags: java

I have installed openjdk-6-jdk  on my machine linux , the function renameTo does not work ?
have you an idea  please about this problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: What error are you getting?  Could you describe in more detail beyond it "does not work"?  It's hard to help you solve a problem when we don't have a good description of what's going on.

Comment: I doubt that this has anything to do with that it's OpenJDK on Linux. There are many reasons why it wouldn't work: for example, some process still has the file that you want to rename opened, you don't have permission to rename the file, or you're trying to rename it across partitions. Tell us more details and show your code.

Comment: At run time the program does not rename the file (it does not moving the file).. i have an error when the programm will use the file in the new destination (when i insert command linux mv in my code java it works !!!)

Comment: If it doesn't work, it means you are doing something wrong. Its not possible to be more specific with the information you have given.

Comment: the same code run correctly on a machine with jdk: java version "1.6.0_20"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.10.1)
OpenJDK Client VM (build 19.0-b09, mixed mode, sharing)
but with other machine with jdk  openjdk-6-jdk does not work

Comment: I have not put the code as it is a bit complicated and I'm trying to simplify the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At run time the program does not rename the file (it does not moving the file).. i have an error when the programm will use the file in the new destination (when i insert command linux mv in my code java it works !!!)

Based on those symptoms, I'd say that you are attempting to rename a file from one file system to another.

The "mv" command can do this, but the `File.renameTo(...)` cannot.  (And incidentally, neither can the "rename" system call.)  This is not an OpenJDK bug.  Rather it is a documented limitation.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) says this:

> *"Many aspects of the behavior of this method are inherently platform-dependent: The rename operation might not be able to move a file from one filesystem to another, it might not be atomic, and it might not succeed if a file with the destination abstract pathname already exists. The return value should always be checked to make sure that the rename operation was successful.*
>
> *Note that the Files class defines the move method to move or rename a file in a platform independent manner."*

---

The fact that it works on some other machine may simply be down to the fact that the source and destination for the move are in the same file system.

Comment: Please, what do you mean byt:attempting to rename a file from one file system to another.(i work in the same machine openjdk-6-jdk) ?

Comment: Read this link: http://tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/sect_03_01.html.  Particularly the stuff about partitions and mount points.  This explains what "file system" means in this context.